# UIWebKit lags when dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, lag

[image]

If you notice, the WebKit view doesn't smoothly disappear, and it's a bit annoying on the eyes.

I'm utilizing the following code:

```
@IBAction func Close(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    println("cancel")
}
```

I'm not sure why this is going on. Using a button as a push back to the original about page works, but it removes the tabbar.

Comment: Try calling `removeAllAnimation` before dismissing the view controller as their may still be some animations conflicting with each other.

Comment: @JakeC. I figured it out. It was actually caused by an extra view behind everything.